# From string to fstring

Tags: python, json, lambda, syntax, f-string

I'm trying to pull a string from JSON, then convert it to an f string to be used dynamically.
Example
Assigned from JSON I get

whose_fault= "{name} started this whole mess"

How to build a lambda to convert it to an f-string and insert the given variable? I just can't quite get my head around it.
I know similar questions have been asked, but no answer seems to quite work for this.

Better question. What's the most pythonic way to insert a variable into a string (which cannot be initially created as an f-string)?
My goal would be a lambda function if possible.
The point being to insert the same variable into whatever string is given where indicated said string.

Comment: f-strings allow arbitrary code execution. Someone can make an f-string install ransomware or email your customers' private data to Nigeria. This is a bad idea - use something else.

Comment: I don't do Python, but as far as I can tell, an [f-string](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/) is a string **literal** that supports interpolation as part of the literal syntax. As such, it's a source code construct. You can't create one dynamically at runtime (if I'm reading correctly) (unless Python has a means of allowing you to execute code in a string, which would be problematic from a security standpoint).

Comment: There is no such thing as f-string in python. Its just a feature to allow you execute a code instead of using concatination.
So if you have a variable `x= 1011`, then you can create another string that contains the variable x in it. Like

`y = f"its now  {x*2}"`, now `y` is a string. not a function or a type

Answer (score 0):

There is no such thing as f-string type object in python. Its just a feature to allow you execute a code and format a string.
So if you have a variable `x= 2020`, then you can create another string that contains the variable x in it. Like

`y = f"It is now {x+1}"`. Now `y` is a string, not a new object type,not a function